# tikz mindmap/tree or graph autolayout

Tags: layout, latex, tikz, dot2tex

[tikz mindmaps](https://tikz.dev/library-mindmaps) are suitable for small layout, however I'm looking for an autolayout mechanism that allows arbitrary content to be layed out automatically.

Example of limitations of tikz mindmaps: If I add grow cyclic to the path, the size and distance of the nodes to each other is not optimal. I imagine a result similar to the output of the graphml editor `yed` which works pretty well, but there's no bindings to TeX afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with the `dot2tex` package in LaTeX:

```
\begin{dot2tex}[tikz,options=-tmath,autosize]
digraph G {
    a [texlbl="\begin{minipage}{10cm} \end{minipage}" ] 
    b [texlbl="C"]
    a -> b -> a
}
\end{dot2tex}
```

Arbitrary markup can be put into the `texlbl` parameter and will be layed out nicely.

It's important to add the `autosize` option and to not include line breaks in the `texlbl` content (consider wrapping in `standalone` for very long content).